# Dictionary.get with multiple values per key - no match

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I would like to retrieve a value from a dictionary in which the key has multiple values. In some instances, there is no key match so I want to return `None`. This is easy with single value keys as `dictionary.get(key,None)`, but what is an easy way to do this with multiple values per key?

```
import datetime
test = {
    u'ID1': {'End Date': None, 'Start Date': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 22, 0, 0)},
    u'ID2': {'End Date': None, 'Start Date': datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 18, 0, 0)}
}


print test.get('ID1','Start Date',None)
print test.get('ID3','Start Date',None)
```

Comment: Possibly a better way to do this is to make the key a tuple, like `test["ID1", "End Date"] = None`, then `test.get(("ID1", "End Date"), None)`.

Comment: to be clear: the key for your dictionary does NOT have multiple values; rather there are nested dicts in your data structure and you need one key for each level.

Comment: just check if the key exists

Answer (score 1):

You have a nested dictionary and will need to perform two lookups. You could create a function that does what you are looking for though.

```
def getNestedDict(d, key1, key2, default):
    result1 = d.get(key1)
    if result1 is None:
        return default
    else:
        return result1.get(key2, default)

print getNestedDict(test, 'ID1', 'Start Date', None)
```

Comment: `None` is the default to `get`. in other words, just call `d.get(key1)`

Comment: what is key2 does not exist? It is probably easier check if the key exists

Comment: Updated comment to be more explicit, showing what key1 and key2 are with an example.

Comment: This can just be simplified to `return d.get(key1, {}).get(key2, default)`

Answer (score 1):

```
test.get('ID1', {}).get('Start Date')
```

Or:

```
try:
    return test['ID1']['Start Date']
except KeyError:
    return None
```

Comment: I really like the first start date, but don't see why it returns None. Could it return a string to? Do you know of any documentation for this?

Comment: `None` is the default return value for `.get()` when the key isn't present.  if you don't want `None`, just use whatever else you want.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get